# Rotate an Image around a point i Windows 8 metro

Tags: c#, animation, windows-8

I want to rotate a image around a point using the flick speed of the user and it should slow down as rotates and the effect should be natural ...

till now I have tried to achieve this using storyboard but was not getting the desired result as the speed of the user can be variable. I have also tried using update loop but I am not able understand how to achieve it.

[image]

I want this start arrow to rotate around the nail.

ant help will be appreciated ...  thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use RotateTransform and set centerx centery to nail position: Then bind Angle to some value and change it to any value you want.

```
<Image.RenderTransform> 
<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotationAngle}" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" /> 
</Image.RenderTransform>
```

Or instead of binding you can use storyboard to change angle (change rectangle controll to image)

```
<Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" Fill="Orange">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotation" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="Rotation" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
    From="1.0" To="40.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
    AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: but i want the speed of the roataion depending upon the swipe speed of the user..